# How to get border width in jQuery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How do I parse the border width from

`style="border: solid 1px black;"`

in jQuery/javascript?

`$elem.css('border-width')`

doesn't do it.

Note I need to parse the width from the css, as the element may be `display:none`

Thanks

**Edit** I'm not actually using an in-line style, I just wrote it that way for simplicity as I didn't realise there was any behavoural difference. It seems to work fine for inline styles though, but still can't get any value from an applied css class.

Comment: In the past, I've avoided problems like this by using visibility: hidden or setting an absolute position far outside the screen (i.e. `left: -10000px`).  If you could do that, a simple `$(elem).outerWidth(false) - $(elem).innerWidth()` would get you the border width.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

<s>You can just use `parseInt();` to parse the border width from `Npx` to `N`:</s>

```
var width = $elem.css('borderWidth'); // 150px
var parsed = parseInt(width);         // 150
```

I had a Google around and it appears in order to get the width of a border you must provide an explicit side of the border:

```
var borderWidth = $elem.css("border-left-width");
```

This is because it's possible for every border to have a different size, style and colour. Unfortunately it doesn't appear to be any simpler than this.

Comment: +1! Hint: Always include the radix: `parseInt(width, 10)`. Default is hexadecimal. `parseInt("08") === 0` and `parseInt("08", 10) === 8`

Comment: You can also use this derivative of ILMV's jsFiddle example to confirm that values set by shorthand properties still return properly: http://jsfiddle.net/s7YAN/1/

Comment: +1, I wasn't sure whether his question was having problems getting the property or parsing it.

Comment: its not a parsing problem, i can't get any value for border width. See comment on the other answer.

Comment: doh! i'd tried `border-left` but not `border-left-width`! what an idiot lol. thanks :)

Comment: No problemo. If you find a better way in the future, please update your question :). I can't believe this is the only way.

Comment: @elusive The default is decimal. For example, `parseInt(10) === 10`. What you're demonstrating is that `parseInt` will interpret the input as octal if it has a leading "0".

Comment: @Andrew B.: Correct! Sorry about that.

Comment: Beware, though, that IE can return non-numbers for `border-whatever-width`, and the [CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#propdef-border-top-width) allows values of "thin", "medium" and "thick" too. This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PCE8a/3/) shows IE returning "middle" as a `border-top-width`. FF and chrome show it as 0px, and parseInt("middle", 10) returns `NaN`, so be sure to test in IE too. I'm _still_ looking for how to get a number of pixels in every case.

Comment: adding on what  Peter V. Mørch said, chrome can return '1px'  so make sure you use the parseint stated above by elusive

Comment: re IE, if you detect IE ... change everything to 50pt comic sans and add a popup message linking to a decent browser using setInterval

Comment: @SamWatkins I don't know how you've only 423 rep.  That's the best advice I've ever seen on SO!

Comment: By the way, border width could be a fraction in which case the right approach would be to use parseFloat(width, 10)

Comment: @SamWatkins in the spirit of SO, I would recommend using setTimeout instead of setInterval :p

Answer (score 10):

```
var bordersOnBothSides = $("#measureMe").outerWidth() - $("#measureMe").innerWidth() );
```

Answer (score 9):

jQuery doesn't allow the use of `-` when referencing a CSS property, so remove the hypen and capitalise the following letter.

```
$elem.css('borderWidth');
```

[Coded in jsFiddle to demonstrate](http://jsfiddle.net/s7YAN/).

Comment: nope, still can't get it to work if the style isn't inline. see http://jsfiddle.net/s7YAN/2/

Comment: @Ben Everard - jQuery does allow hyphnes - its just short-hand CSS that is not allowed - so left-border-width is ok, but border-width is not.

Comment: Your statement is not true. Changed fiddle to `border-width` and it still works: http://jsfiddle.net/s7YAN/500/

Comment: From jQuery's documentation: http://api.jquery.com/css/ --My experience is hyphens for CSS properties works within quotes. I use camelCase when setting multiple properties in an object, i.e.:
$(this).css({borderWidth: "2px", borderColor: "blue"}); ..because hyphens are an operator when used outside quotes in JS, as opposed to a character.

Comment: This solution is not working at EDGE & FireFox, it will return string empty, you must calculate the `border-left-width` + border-right-width, etc.

Answer (score 7):

To complete Generic's answer when seeking he left border and to include elusive's comment about radix:

```
<div style="border-style:solid;border-left-width:15px;"></div>
```

in script:

```
var width =parseInt($('div').css('borderLeftWidth'),10);
alert(width);
```

Answer (score 3):

If u have equal border widh for element, or u need left, top border width, plain js:

```
elem.clientLeft; //get left border of element
elem.clientTop; //get top border of element
```

To get right, bottom border use jquery+css:

```
parseInt($(elem).css('borderLeftWidth'),10); // 10 use to get result in dec, not hex number system
```