# jQuery CSS borderWidth

Tags: jquery, border

I'm unable to get the border width of an element. I tried the following but it shows empty results. Check http://jsfiddle.net/s7YAN/14/

```
$('div').css('borderWidth');
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get border width in jQuery/javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787502/how-to-get-border-width-in-jquery-javascript)

Comment: not a duplicate for the solution there dont work here

Answer (score 11, accepted):

borderWidth is syntactic sugar for setting each border's width independently. You can't assume that every border's width is the same, so you need to ask for a specific border's width.

```
$("div").css("borderTopWidth");
```

Comment: that's an entirely different problem :). you can't just set a border width without setting a color and a style. http://jsfiddle.net/s7YAN/18/

Answer (score 6):

For border-width, you need to specify the side of the border.  `borderWidth`/`border-width` is a shortcut for all of the `border-width`'s at once.

```
$( function() {
    alert($('div').css("border-top-width"));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZsSmp/

Also, you need to specify more than a border width for it to be valid.  Just specifying a border-width does not make a border.  It needs a color and style, too:

```
border: 2px solid black;
```

Comment: Interesting, because "border-width" works in Chrome and Safari 6 on the mac, but not in Firefox on the mac.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you don't define the border-style in your CSS, so it's default to none, whose width is 0px.

Also, you should specify which border (left, top) for border-width is just a shortcut for all borders.

Comment: the bit about border-style defaulting to none just solved my hair pulling moment: thanks!