# jQuery's CSS method

Tags: jquery, css

HTML:

```
<div id="that" style="margin-left: 10px; border-width: 2px"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
// alerts "10px 0px" which is strange, isn't it?
alert($('#that').css('margin-left') + ' ' +  $('#that').css('border-width'));
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vZpAv/

Why does jQuery behave like that? Aren't it supposed to get the 2px? Firstly, I thought it was because of the dash in the CSS property (as `css('borderWidth')` works properly) but as you can see it does work well for `margin-left`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery CSS borderWidth](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904380/jquery-css-borderwidth)

Answer (score 7):

`border-width` is used for setting the border width of each border on an element, but you can't assume that each border has the same width. As a result, you need to run something like:

`$('#that').css("borderTopWidth");`

But this will still return 0px, because you can't set a border width without setting a colour and style.

Comment: Border color isn't necessary. He only needs to specify border style.

Comment: Ah, I always thought they were both required. Every day is a school day. Anyway, at least it solves his problem...

Answer (score 1):

use Fire fox and fire bug and try to use

`Console.log();` instead of alerts

Answer (score 0):

You can use following piece of code:

```
alert($('div').css('margin-left') + ' ' + $.style($('div')[0], 'borderWidth'));
```