# Get border style with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

How can i get border style with jQuery. The following is not working

```
$('#get').click(function() {
    var x = $('div').css('borderStyle');
    alert(x)
})
```

Check http://jsfiddle.net/s7YAN/31/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
alert($("div.myel").css("border-top-style"));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jbrooksuk/YJQAS/

It seems that you're unable to get the whole border style in one go. You need to explicitly state which part of it you want.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently you must specify the side.

Like that :

```
var x = $('div').css("border-left-style");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s7YAN/45/

I think it's because each side could have a different size, color and style.

Answer (score 0):

The [jQuery `.css()` manual](http://api.jquery.com/css/) states that:

> Shorthand CSS properties (e.g. margin,
>   background, border) are not supported.
>   For example, if you want to retrieve
>   the rendered margin, use:
>   $(elem).css('marginTop') and
>   $(elem).css('marginRight'), and so on.

Basically `border-style` is just a shorthand for setting the style of the border on the four sides. It can also be used like `border-style: dotted solid double dashed;` but normally you just write `border-style: dashed;` that is why it feels like a simple property. The same happens with `margin`, saying `margin: 20px;` actually means `margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;` (it is also a shorthand property).

That is why you need to use `border-top-style`, `border-right-style`, etc. to get the border style.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. it appears you have to set an explicit side: 
[How to get border width in jQuery/javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787502/how-to-get-border-width-in-jquery-javascript)
Not exactly the same, but the same principle should apply to you, as demonstrated here:

```
alert($('div').css('border-top-style'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s7YAN/54/