# JQuery 1.10.1 .css() is not working in Firefox 22

Tags: jquery, css, firefox

I'm having trouble getting style attributes from jQuery with Firefox.

My file...

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
function search() {
alert($("#namesearch").css("border-style"));
}
</script>


<input style="border-style:solid" id="namesearch">
<input type=button onclick="search();" value="Search">
</body>
</html>
```

In Chrome 27.0.1453.116 m and Internet Explorer 8, I get an alert that says "solid".

In Firefox 22, I get a blank alert.

Comment: Possible duplicat [Get border style with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910705/get-border-style-with-jquery).