# Get data from above cell

Tags: jquery, html-table, traversal

I need to retrieve the bottom border width of the cell above the clicked cell.

```
var $this = $(this);
var col = $this.parent().children().index($this);
var row = $this.parent().parent().children().index($this.parent());
var bordWidth= ($this.parents('tr:eq('+(row-1)+')').find('td:eq('+col+')').css("border-bottom-width"));
```

Comment: I typed the answer in your previous question, but you deleted it before I was able to post it. Instead of posting a new question, edit the original question instead, to include the new details.

Comment: I think [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787502/how-to-get-border-width-in-jquery-javascript) should answer your question.

Comment: @RobW- Sorry about that. My previous question was too broad and was turing out to be 10 questions instead of one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this.

```
var $this = $(this);
var $tr = $this.parent();
var col = $tr.children().index($this);
var bordWidth = $tr.prev().children().eq(col).css("border-bottom-width");
```

`.prev()` will get the previous `tr` element and then using `.children()` get all the `td`'s and get the required td using `eq()` method.

Comment: Keep in mind that this won't work if there are colSpan > 1 set on the previous tr. This is the case when you are at cell 2 of row 2 and the previous cell has only one cell with colSpan of 2. In this case eq(col) would return an empty selector for the previous row.