# How do I get position x and y from jQuery ui draggable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Here an example http://jsfiddle.net/naqbq/

How do I grab current position for `x` and `y` after re-position the image?

```
<input type="hidden" name="source_x" id="source_x" />
<input type="hidden" name="source_y" id="source_y" />
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the `stop` callback, you can use `ui.helper` to access the dragged element. Then use `offset` on it, as Brad suggested:

```
$("#image").draggable({
    stop:function(event,ui) {
        var wrapper = $("#wrapper").offset();
        var borderLeft = parseInt($("#wrapper").css("border-left-width"),10);
        var borderTop = parseInt($("#wrapper").css("border-top-width"),10);
        var pos = ui.helper.offset();
        $("#source_x").val(pos.left - wrapper.left - borderLeft);
        $("#source_y").val(pos.top - wrapper.top - borderTop);
        alert($("#source_x").val() + "," + $("#source_y").val());
    }
});​
```

Then, it's just a matter of adjusting it to your wrapper - subtracting its offset and its border's width - and setting it to your input's `val`. <strike>(sorry for hardcoding the border, but I couldn't extract it using `css`)</strike> (*Edit*: there it is! found the solution in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3787535/520779))

http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/naqbq/4/

Answer (score 5):

You can use jQuery's `.offset()`.

http://api.jquery.com/offset/

```
alert($('#image').offset().top);
alert($('#image').offset().left);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the built in stop event:

```
$("#image").draggable({
    stop: function() { 
        // check for positioning here using .css or .offset
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can obtain the top, and lef:

```
$('selector').draggable({
  drag: function(event, ui) {
    ui.position.top; // .left
    // or
    $('selector').position().top; // current position of an element relative to the offset parent
    $('selector').offset(); // retrieves the current position relative to the document. 
  }
})
```