# How can I drag an icon inside google maps?

Tags: google-maps

I would like to be able to have an icon, placed outside of a google map. Then i would like to have this icon dragged and dropped INTO google maps and use it as a google maps marker.
Is that possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this post in the [Google Maps Javascript API v3 group](https://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/browse_thread/thread/adec0050cd340390/fef0e8df166f08db?lnk=gst&q=drag+marker+onto+map#fef0e8df166f08db)

Points to this example:
http://www.wolfpil.de/v3/drag-from-outside.html

**code snippet (unobfuscated)**

```js
var map, iw, drag_area, actual, mark;
var overview, zIndex = 0;

function helper() {
  this.setMap(map);
  this.draw = function() {};
}
helper.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

function fillMarker(icon) {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + icon + ")";
  var left;
  if (mark.id == "m1") {
    left = "0px";
  } else if (mark.id == "m2") {
    left = "50px";
  } else if (mark.id == "m3") {
    left = "100px";
  }
  div.style.left = left;
  div.id = mark.id;
  div.className = "drag";
  div.onmousedown = div.ontouchstart = initDrag;
  drag_area.replaceChild(div, mark);
  mark = null;
}

function createDraggedMarker(latlng, icon) {
  var icon = {
    url: icon,
    size: new google.maps.Size(32, 32),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(15, 32)
  };
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    map: map,
    clickable: true,
    draggable: true,
    crossOnDrag: false,
    optimized: false,
    icon: icon,
    zIndex: zIndex
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
    actual = marker;
    var lat = actual.getPosition().lat();
    var lng = actual.getPosition().lng();
    var contentStr = "<div class='infowindow'>" + lat.toFixed(6) + ", " + lng.toFixed(6) + "<\/div>";
    iw.setContent(contentStr);
    iw.open(map, this);
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "dragstart", function() {
    if (actual == marker) iw.close();
    zIndex += 1;
    marker.setZIndex(zIndex);
  });
}

function initDrag(evt) {
  function getPt(evt) {
    var pt = {};
    if (evt && evt.touches && evt.touches.length) {
      pt.x = evt.touches[0].clientX;
      pt.y = evt.touches[0].clientY;
    } else {
      if (!evt) var evt = window.event;
      pt.x = evt.clientX;
      pt.y = evt.clientY;
    }
    return pt;
  };
  var drag = function(mEvt) {
    if (mark && mark.className == "drag") {
      var pt = getPt(mEvt),
        x = pt.x - o.x,
        y = pt.y - o.y;
      mark.style.left = (mark.x + x) + "px";
      mark.style.top = (mark.y + y) + "px";
      mark.onmouseup = mark.ontouchend = function() {
        var mapDiv = map.getDiv(),
          mapLeft = mapDiv.offsetLeft,
          mapTop = mapDiv.offsetTop,
          mapWidth = mapDiv.offsetWidth,
          mapHeight = mapDiv.offsetHeight;
        var dragLeft = drag_area.offsetLeft,
          dragTop = drag_area.offsetTop,
          iconWidth = mark.offsetWidth,
          iconHeight = mark.offsetHeight;
        var newLeft = mark.offsetLeft + dragLeft + iconWidth / 2;
        var newTop = mark.offsetTop + dragTop + iconHeight / 2;
        if (dragLeft > mapLeft && newLeft < (mapLeft + mapWidth) && newTop > mapTop && newTop < (mapTop + mapHeight)) {
          var offset = 1;
          var divPt = new google.maps.Point(newLeft - mapLeft - offset, newTop - mapTop + (iconHeight / 2));
          var proj = overview.getProjection();
          var latlng = proj.fromContainerPixelToLatLng(divPt);
          var icon = mark.style.backgroundImage.slice(4, -1).replace(/"/g, "");
          createDraggedMarker(latlng, icon);
          fillMarker(icon);
        }
      };
    }
    return false;
  };
  if (!evt) var evt = window.event;
  mark = evt.target ? evt.target : evt.srcElement ? evt.srcElement : evt.touches ? evt.touches[0].target : null;
  if (mark.className != "drag") {
    if (d.cancelable) d.preventDefault();
    mark = null;
    return;
  } else {
    zIndex++;
    mark.style.zIndex = zIndex.toString();
    mark.x = mark.offsetLeft;
    mark.y = mark.offsetTop;
    var o = getPt(evt);
    if (evt.type === "touchstart") {
      mark.onmousedown = null;
      mark.ontouchmove = drag;
      mark.ontouchend = function() {
        mark.ontouchmove = null;
        mark.ontouchend = null;
        mark.ontouchstart = initDrag;
      };
    } else {
      document.onmousemove = drag;
      document.onmouseup = function() {
        document.onmousemove = null;
        document.onmouseup = null;
        if (mark) mark = null;
      };
    }
  }
  return false;
}

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.052491, 9.84375),
    zoom: 4,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    streetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE, google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN]
    },
    panControl: false,
    zoomControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
    }
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
  iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function() {
    if (iw) iw.close();
  });
  drag_area = document.getElementById("markers");
  var divArray = drag_area.getElementsByTagName("div");
  for (var i = 0; i < divArray.length; i++) {
    var div = divArray[i];
    div.onmousedown = div.ontouchstart = initDrag;
  }
  overview = new helper();
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#map {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 25px 10px 14px;
  width: 64%;
  height: 70%;
}
#desc {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 25px 10px 20px;
  width: 10em;
}
#markers {
  position: absolute;
  top: 140px;
  left: 70%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 110px;
}
.drag {
  position: absolute;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}
.infowindow {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 180px;
  height: 60px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 890px) {
  body,
  html,
  #map {
    margin: 0;
  }
  #map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
  }
  #desc {
    margin: 100px 14px 0;
    width: 93%;
  }
  .include >b {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 17px;
  }
  #markers {
    /* center horizontal and do not overlap the map */
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 10em;
    height: 6em;
    margin-top: 5em;
    margin-left: -5em;
  }
  #markers > p {
    margin-top: 0;
    font-size: 80%;
  }
  .infowindow {
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 25px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,places&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<h3>Drag Markers to the Map</h3>

<div id="map"></div>
<div id="desc"></div>
<div id="markers">
  <p>Drag the markers to a location on the map</p>
  <div id="m1" class="drag" style="left:0; background-image: url('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png')"></div>
  <div id="m2" class="drag" style="left:50px; background-image: url('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/green.png')"></div>
  <div id="m3" class="drag" style="left:100px; background-image: url('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/yellow.png')"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer contains some obfuscated code. It took me quite a lot of time to find something a bit more tangible so since this answer comes up first in google search I thought will share something for a good start.

Note: `window.map` is where I store reference to my map. Also for cross-browser compatibility I am using jquery-ui draggable (was already included in my project so why not reusing it).

```
    var pixelToLatlng = function(xcoor, ycoor)
    {
        var ne = window.map.getBounds().getNorthEast();
        var sw = window.map.getBounds().getSouthWest();
        var projection = window.map.getProjection();
        var topRight = projection.fromLatLngToPoint(ne);
        var bottomLeft = projection.fromLatLngToPoint(sw);
        var scale = 1 << window.map.getZoom();

        var newLatlng = projection.fromPointToLatLng(new google.maps.Point(xcoor / scale + bottomLeft.x, ycoor / scale + topRight.y));
        return newLatlng;
    };

    $(".draggable").draggable(
    {
        helper: "clone",
        appendTo: window.map.getDiv(),
        cursorAt: { left: 5, top: 5 },
        stop: function(event, ui)
        {
            var wrapper = $(window.map.getDiv());
            var map_div_pos = wrapper.offset();
            var map_div_border_left = parseInt(wrapper.css("border-left-width"),10);
            var map_div_border_top = parseInt(wrapper.css("border-top-width"),10);

            var mouse_pos = ui.helper.offset();
            lat_lng = pixelToLatlng(mouse_pos.left - map_div_border_left - map_div_pos.left, mouse_pos.top - map_div_border_top - map_div_pos.top);

            window.add_group_marker = new google.maps.Marker(
            {
                position: lat_lng,
                map: window.map,
                zIndex: Math.round(lat_lng.lat()*-100000)<<5
            });
        }
    });
```

---

Credits:

- `pixelToLatlng` was found here: http://www.magicalrosebud.com/how-to-use-googlemaps-api-frompointtolatlng/
- Hints on calculating x/y when using jquery-ui draggable: [How do I get position x and y from jQuery ui draggable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9810929/how-do-i-get-position-x-and-y-from-jquery-ui-draggable)