# Drag and drop button on google maps to create marker

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin

I am trying to create a marker on google maps with drag and dropping a button on google maps on the drop position.

my original plan was to simluate a click on the position where the button would be dropped but i can't find any method to simulate a click on a specific position.

Has anyone tried something similar? What would be the best way?

Comment: You could always put a marker on the map and then allow user to move it (draggable property).

Comment: the thing is, that the user has to navigate in the map and i don't think it's possible to make a marker static to the screen position (?)
And generating (and deleting the old) a new marker every time the map view changes is quite an ugly solution i think.

Comment: Related question: [How can I drag an icon inside google maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16778930/how-can-i-drag-an-icon-inside-google-maps)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you found the dropped position because, in your question, you want to simulate click on the specific position, therefore my answer is:

You can find the LatLng by dropped position

```
val projection = googleMap.getProjection()

// Returns the geographic location that corresponds to a screen location
val latLng = projection.fromScreenLocation(Point(yourX, yourY))
```

and after that is easy to create the marker

```
 // Creating a marker
 val markerOptions = MarkerOptions()

 // Setting the position for the marker
 markerOptions.position(latLng)
```

Answer (score 0):

my idea is to add a transparent view above the Map when the user click on the button, after drag on this view, recover x, y in the screen and make a projection on the map to add the marker , there is a method in the map sdk that gives latitude and langitude from the x, y coordinates of the screen