# Dynamic width using jQuery - Custom Select Box

Tags: jquery, css, dynamic, width, drop-down-menu

I've made a custom select box using CSS and jQuery and until tonight I thought I was done.. but no..

The code can be viewed and played with here http://jsfiddle.net/nvv35/5/

The problem is that when using Firefox, IE or Safari the select box doesn't get the correct width. If you look at the demo using Chrome you'll see nothing wrong. The jQuery code sets the desired width for the "label" and the box looks pretty much perfect, but not in the browsers mentioned before..

The select label is way too short. Instead of getting the same width as the longest child in the drop-down it's cut off right after the text.. I just simply can't find where the problem lies..

So, I need your help guys 'n gals.

**UPDATE**

Final code: http://jsfiddle.net/nvv35/9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`parseInt($(this).next(".selectBox").css("border-width"), 10)` is resulting a NaN.

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nvv35/8/

Change your code to as follows:

**Update:**To get the border-width correctly specific side of the border needs to be pecified. (Check: [How to get border width in jQuery/javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787502/how-to-get-border-width-in-jquery-javascript))

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").css("display", "none");
  $(".selectContainer").css("display", "inline-block");
  $(".selectHead").each(function() {
    var newWidth = $(this).next(".selectBox").outerWidth();
      var borderWidth = parseInt($(this).next(".selectBox").css("border-left-width").replace(/[^0-9]/g,""), 10) ;
      if(isNaN(borderWidth)) borderWidth  = 0;
    newWidth = newWidth - (borderWidth * 2);
    $(this).css("width", newWidth + "px");
  });
  $(".selectHead").on("click", function() {
    $(this).next(".selectBox").show();
    $(this).closest(".selectContainer").on("mouseleave", function() {
      $(this).find(".selectBox").hide();
    });
  });
  $("li", ".optionsBox").on("click", function() {
    var newValue = $(this).attr("id").replace(/(.*)-/,"");
    $(this).closest(".selectContainer").next("select").val(newValue);
    $(this).closest(".selectBox").prev(".selectHead").html($(this).html());
    $(this).closest(".selectBox").find(".optionSelected").removeClass("optionSelected");
    $(this).addClass("optionSelected");
    $(this).closest(".selectBox").hide();
  });
});
```

Comment: Ah, yeah, you're right. The problem seems to be the border subtraction.. Right now, though, the box gets too big since it results in NaN in all those browsers and automatically gets the 0 value as written in the code. I could just manually add a 2 to the code and fix it, but how can I get it to fetch the border-width and still work in the those browsers?

Comment: Thanks for the update. Just happened to find that exact same page myself just a minute ago, so managed to solve it :) Thanks again for the answer! +1 and Accepted

Answer (score 0):

```
function customSelect(){
 $('.custom-select a.open').on('click', function () {
    if ( $(this).next().hasClass('active') ) {
        $(this).next().removeClass('active').slideUp(250);
    }
    else{
        $(this).next().addClass('active').slideDown(250);
    }
});

$('.custom-select ul.options li').on('click', function () {
    var value = $(this).data('value');        
    $(this).parent().removeClass('active').slideUp(250);
    $(this).parent().parent().prev().attr('value', value);
    $(this).parent().prev().text(value);
});
}
customSelect();
```

- See more at: http://www.pointmycode.com/customize-select-box-with-css-and-jquery/