# Better way to get the border width in javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, getcomputedstyle

I use this :

```
var playGard =document.getElementsByClassName("playGard")[0];

var borderW= getComputedStyle(playGard,null).getPropertyValue('border-left-width').substr(0,2);
```

I get the value "10".

There is a better shorter way in javascript?

(Get the value as a  number)

Comment: Seems about right, that's the way to get the computed style

Comment: You have your answer in your question itself!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get border width in jQuery/javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787502/how-to-get-border-width-in-jquery-javascript)

Comment: document.getElementById("ppp").style.border.. this will give you border

Comment: You can shorten it a bit in pure JS: `var borderW = parseInt(getComputedStyle(playGard).borderLeftWidth);`

Comment: @Raviteja There's no mention of jQuery in this question...

Comment: @PankajSewalia This will only give values that are actually in the `style="..."` attribute of that element, but not values applied from `<style>` tags or external CSS files.

Comment: @Moran  do you want it in javascript only ?? do you use jquery ??

Comment: @SajadKaruthedath Yes, using only javascript .

Comment: @Moran ok, i will remove my answer then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, `substr(0, 2)` is not a good idea, because it won't work if the width is less than 10, or greater than 100.

Instead, just remove the "px" string (if it's there; it might not be if the value is 0):

```
+val.replace('px', '')
```

The leading `+` is to convert this to a number.

#### But why?

The more interesting question is why you're trying to get the border width. What were you planning to do with it? Using `getComputedStyle` is a bit of an anti-pattern. It often indicates that you're trying to maintain application state within CSS, which is never a good idea.

Comment: It for get the width/height without the border.i play a little game with a circle that if touch the border the circle change to red.